# How to prevent multiple outputs from being returned in a proc

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that gets called like this:

```
INSERT #ABC
EXEC proc_123
```

Now I have to modify the proc_123 and now it returns multiple outputs and my code crashes because the insert to #ABC is failing.

proc_123 looks like this on the bottom, I added this:

```
exec proc_logging 'abc'
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f FROM alpha
```

The proc_logging returns some output, and I cannot modify this proc at this point in time.

**Is there a way I can block it from returning anything or effecting my stored procedures output?**

Comment: AFAIK, with insert...exec, you can only insert the first resultset. so if your proc_123 would have it's original resultset first, your insert...exec should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table in the proc and before the extra exec proc  insert into that temp table which you can then ignore and the proc will have only one table returning data.